# how do I remove duplicates in Javascript array with out sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

So I am making a game that calculates love percentage based on the letters in two peoples names with the word love.

In the code below I am counting the number of times a letter appears in the value array
then I want to push this value into the nums Array for each unique letter.
However I am not sure how I can get it to not repeat for each time the letter appears in the value array.
Also I can not sort the array or the game will not calculate properly.

so for example the below value array should push 3 for s only once into the nums array.

```
var value =["s", "a", "m", "a", "n", "t", "h", "a", "w", "h", "i", "t", "e", "l", "o", "v", "e", "s", "J", "a", "c", "k", "h", "a", "r", "r", "i", "s"]; 


function trueLoveGame(value){

    var nums=[];

    for(var i =0; i < value.length;i++){
        var count = 0;
        for(var a = 0; a < value.length;a++){
            if(value[i] === value[a]){  
                count++;
            }
            else{

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: see if the letter's in the already before pushing it, then. or you should be using the letters as the array keys instead, e.g. `letters['s'] = 3`, so you don't have to worry about uniques - using the letters as keys will automatically make each letter unique, because you can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Im not sure what that means?

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ? an object or array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as it wasn't clear exactly what was required. This should answer both possibilities that I think you could be asking.

```
var userArray = ["s", "a", "m", "a", "n", "t", "h", "a", "w", "h", "i", "t", "e", "l", "o", "v", "e", "s", "J", "a", "c", "k", "h", "a", "r", "r", "i", "s"];

function unique(array) {
    var unique = [];

    array.forEach(function (value) {
        if (unique.indexOf(value) === -1) {
            unique.push(value);
        }
    });

    return unique;
}

function count(array) {
    var obj = {};

    array.forEach(function (value) {
        obj[value] = (obj[value] || 0) + 1;
    });

    return obj;
}


console.log(userArray);
console.log(unique(userArray));
console.log(count(userArray));
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/cJyfh/)

Comment: The way the game works is it takes the letters of two peoples names. For example: sara love martin, then is counts the number of times the letter appears and adds it to a new array. The first and last values of that array will be added and you will continue to add the numbers inward till moving them to a new array and take those values and do the same until there is only two numbers

Comment: those numbers are the percentage of love

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you need to get key value pairs. You can try something as given below to get an object of letter-count pairs.

```
function trueLoveGame(value){


    var nums={};

    for(var i =0; i < value.length;i++){
       var letter = value[i];
       nums[letter] =   nums[letter] || 0;
       nums[letter]++;
    }

    return nums;
}
```